# select best row available from each group each item for dates available

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have data like this

```
Group id Date       
1   1   2015-01-01
2   1   2015-01-01
1   1   2015-02-01
2   1   2015-02-01
1   1   2015-03-01
1   2   2015-04-01
2   2   2015-04-01
```

Want to select each record for each day for each id from Group 2 if available. If Group 2 row is not available then return Group 1 record for that date.for each id there is always record with Group 1. so End result should be

```
Group id Date
2   1   2015-01-01
2   1   2015-02-01
1   1   2015-03-01
2   2   2015-04-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` window function

```
select * from
(
select row_number()over(partition by Date order by Group) as RN,*
from yourtable
) A
Where RN =1
```

If a `Date` has more than one `Group = 1` and if you want to return all `Group = 1` records for a `date` then use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct max(gid) as  gid over(partition by id,[grp_date] order by id), id,grp_date
from test
order by grp_date
```